# Equivalence of Quantum Mechanical Systems in Cartesian and Polar Coordinates for a Free Particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, coordinate-systems, quantization

I am exploring the quantum mechanical description of a free particle in 2 dimensions and seeking clarification on the equivalence of formulations in Cartesian and polar coordinates. The core of my inquiry revolves around whether these two coordinate systems yield the same physical predictions, particularly in terms of probabilities for particle measurements.

**Initial Formulations:**

1. **Cartesian Coordinates (x, y):** The wave function is $\Psi(x,y,t)$, and the Hamiltonian is represented as:

   $$
      \hat{H} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right)
      $$

   The Schrödinger equation is:

   $$
      i\hbar \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = \hat{H} \Psi
      $$
2. **Polar Coordinates (r, θ):** The wave function is $\tilde{\Psi}(r,\theta,t)$, and the Hamiltonian in polar coordinates is:

   $$
      \hat{H} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \right)
      $$

   Corresponding Schrödinger equation:

   $$
      i\hbar \frac{\partial \tilde{\Psi}}{\partial t} = \hat{H} \tilde{\Psi}
      $$

Given an initial condition $\Psi(x,y,0) = f(x,y) = \tilde{f}(r,\theta) = \tilde{\Psi}(r,\theta,0)$, I am interested in understanding whether the evolution of these wave functions in their respective coordinate systems leads to identical physical predictions.

**Question 1.**

Specifically, for a given region $R$ in Cartesian coordinates, corresponding to $\tilde{R}$ in polar coordinates, will the probabilities of measuring the particle at time $t$ in $R$ or $\tilde{R}$ be the same when calculated using $\Psi(x,y,t)$ and $\tilde{\Psi}(r,\theta,t)$, respectively?

**Question 2.**

In the formulation above, we have quantized the free particle in Cartesian coordinates, and then we have transformed the Hamiltonian to polar coordinates. What if I do the Hamiltonian formulation of the classical free particle in polar coordinates, and then quantize promoting $\theta$, $r$ and their conjugate momenta to operators? Would I obtain the same system?

Comment: 1. The same integral would be different in different coordinate systems integrated over? 2. Detail your proposed quantization scheme.

Comment: The case of a general coordinate system is nicely discussed in chapter 8 of Luis Sobrino's Elements of non-relativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: For your particular example, see from page 192 on in Greiner's QM book. I think there are one or two posts also here on PSE. It is often said that the safest way to quantize is to first do it in cartesian coordinates and then go to e.g. polar coordinates. I think a general way is to see the wave function as a complex line bundle (but I cannot give you a particular reference here, but you should be able to find something).

Comment: Regarding my above comments, see: [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/485218/wave-function-as-a-section-of-a-complex-line-bundle-to-do-qm-in-polar-coordinate), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/501184/hamiltonian-operator-in-polar-coordinates-with-momentum-operators) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216226/canonical-commutation-relations-in-arbitrary-canonical-coordinates) and links therein...and I think there are even more here in this forum.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have edited the questions for clarity.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thank you for your links. In particular, my question is completely answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/515863/207777)